# How to delete hasMany relationship in Laravel without key

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete hasMany relationship but to no avail.

I have three tables: `users`, `user_details`, and `manufacturers`

`User` hasOne `user_details`

`user_details` belongsTo `user`

`manufacturers` have many `users` through `user_details`

Now when admin deletes manufacturer, it needs to delete all user_details who has that manufacturer_id and all related users.

My tables:

### Users:

```
id, unique_id, first_name, last_name, user_name, email, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

### User_details

```
id, user_id, avatar, locale, role_id, manufacturer_id, account_status, hospital_id, phone, city_id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

### Manufacturers

```
id, name, status, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
    /**
     * @return bool|null
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function softDelete()
    {
        $this->brand_presentations()->delete();
        $this->details()->delete();
        return parent::delete();
    }
```

And here I have my relations:

```
public function brand_presentations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Brand_presentations::class, 'manufacturer_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}

public function details()
{
   return $this->hasMany(User_details::class, 'manufacturer_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

This gives me all the way to the `user_details`, but I cannot get users. How can I get the users?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you need to loop through your details to be able to delete the user

```
/**
 * @return bool|null
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function softDelete()
{
    $this->brand_presentations()->delete();
    $details = $this->details
       foreach($details as $detail) {
          $user = detail->user
          // Delete or access user here
          $detail->delete()
       }
}
```